How can I save/backup all Outlook folders, and view the messages without Outlook
OK - I have had it with Microsoft's Exchange and Outlook email.
I have a "hosted" Exchange account. I am not (and never have been) "proficient" in Exchange administration. And I am tired of trying to keep up with all of the changes Microsoft makes "in the background". I want to free myself from Microsoft's grip: from their grubby licensing practices, and their arcane email "management". I want to remove/delete/uninstall the Outlook application from all of my computers.
However... I still need to be able to access the tons of email and email-attachments that I have accumulated. Honestly - I do not even know where or how all of this is stored! Used to be (IIRC) all email could be saved from Outlook in something called "offline folders", but I have only a dim recollection of that.
So my question is (as stated in the subject):
How do I save or backup all of my Outlook email messages, and be able to view them without access to an Outlook application?

If you don't read exported messages through Outlook, you may need to use a tool to read the .pst file, or open it using a variety of email clients, such as Thunderbird.
Export Your Emails to a PST File:
Open Outlook and go to File > Open & Export > Import/Export.
The exported file format is .pst, which you can't view directly, so you'll need to use a third-party tool viewer. For example: Kernel Outlook PST Viewer. SysTools PST Viewer. MailsDaddy Free PST Viewer.

For macOS users, check out 'MacUncle PST Viewer'

Thanks for this! Much appreciated & apologies I was so slow on the 'acceptance'... I thought I might get a better answer - one that was available for macOS (yeah - failed to mention that)...   And then it got lost in my open tabs LOL

For macOS users, there is MacUncle PST Viewer, and this. I found these using this search.
